# Apache Tomcat will not complete startup after a certain .war File is deployed

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security, war

I have a Java web application that I am trying to deploy to our company's application server. It uses spring and spring-security. Everything works correctly when I run the application in Tomcat from Eclipse but when I try and deploy the .war file into a standalone Tomcat instance the server does not even finish starting up.

These are the catalina logs from the last attempt:

```
Jan 30, 2014 1:16:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.23 using APR version 1.4.6.
Jan 30, 2014 1:16:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random       [true].
Jan 30, 2014 1:16:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized with version OpenSSL 1.0.0g 18 Jan 2012
Jan 30, 2014 1:16:40 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 30, 2014 1:16:40 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Jan 30, 2014 1:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2567 ms
Jan 30, 2014 1:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 30, 2014 1:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
Jan 30, 2014 1:16:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Jan 30, 2014 1:16:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Jan 30, 2014 1:16:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive MyApp.war
```

And then startup stops.

These are the localhost logs:

```
Jan 30, 2014 1:16:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

And then nothing...

All of the other log files for this last attempt are blank.

Any insight you guys might have would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the war actually expanding into `webapps`?

Comment: Is there enough space remaining on hard drive?

Comment: But somewhere some error logs should be available look up to inside tomcat logs `apache-tomcat-x.x.xx\logs`

Comment: Yes the .war file is expanding. 
There is definitely enough space on the hard drive. 
Where can I look up these other error logs?

Comment: here `apache-tomcat-x.x.xx\logs`. The logs folder inside tomcat.

Comment: I already posted everything in those log files

Comment: I think my problem is that I need to point to the .ini files explicitly in my tomcat installation

Comment: You may also change to log level to debug to get some more informations. I guess there is an issue with the Spring configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by not setting the JAVA_OPTS property to point to my .ini files.

I included this in my startup script:

```
set JAVA_OPTS= -DLOGCONFIG=%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\logging.ini -DINIFILE=%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\webapps.ini
```

and it ran succesfully